# How to resolve several deferred inside `promise.then()`

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need run several function parallel inside promise.then()
I tried to use code like bellow, but it work not correct:

```
function fadeElement(selector){
        return function () {
            return $(selector).fadeOut(400).promise();
        }
}

function runParallel(owner, promises) {
    return function () {
        var differed = new $.Deferred();
        var resolveDiffered = function () { differed.resolve(); };
        $.when.apply(owner, promises).
            then(resolveDiffered);
        return differed.promise();
    }
}

FormInput.prototype.ReloadPage = function(){
    var firstOne = fadeElement('#element_Id_1');
    var firstTwo = fadeElement('#element_Id_2');
    var firstThree = fadeElement('#element_Id_3');

    var secondOne = fadeElement('#element_Id_4');

    var thirdOne = fadeElement('#element_Id_5');
    var thirdTwo = fadeElement('#element_Id_6');

    $.when(firstOne(), firstTwo(), firstThree())
    .then(secondOne)
    .then(
        runParallel(this, [thirdOne(), thirdTwo()])
    );
}
```

`firstOne`, `firstTwo`, `firstThree`, `secondOne` are runs without 400ms duration.

`thirdOne`, `thirdTwo` - not run at all.

I think I have a mistake in `runParallel`, but I havn't enough knowledge to understend where. I think so, becouse this code will work:

```
$.when(firstOne(), firstTwo(), firstThree())
.then(secondOne)
.then(thirdOne)
.then(thirdTwo);
```

Comment: runParallel will not do anything, it will just return a function... have you tried to run that function?

Comment: @Crisim No, because then() have parameter, that must be a function, that will return promise object.

Comment: sorry, i've misread....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you were calling `thirdOne` and `thirdTwo` (and thus starting the fading process) when you passed those functions to `runParallel`:

```
.then(
    runParallel(this, [thirdOne(), thirdTwo()])
);
```

Instead, you should remove the final `()` and pass functions to `runParallel`, which should map each method to the result of calling it. Changing the placement of when each promise-generating function is called will allow the fading process to be delayed until be after the other promises have completed:

```js
function fadeElement(selector) {
  return function() {
    return $(selector).fadeOut(400).promise();
  }
}

function runParallel(owner, promises) {
  return function() {
    return $.when.apply(owner, promises.map($.call, $.call))
  }
}

FormInput.prototype.ReloadPage = function() {
  var firstOne = fadeElement('#element_Id_1');
  var firstTwo = fadeElement('#element_Id_2');
  var firstThree = fadeElement('#element_Id_3');

  var secondOne = fadeElement('#element_Id_4');

  var thirdOne = fadeElement('#element_Id_5');
  var thirdTwo = fadeElement('#element_Id_6');

  $.when(firstOne(), firstTwo(), firstThree())
    .then(secondOne)
    .then(
      runParallel(this, [thirdOne, thirdTwo])
    );
}


function FormInput () {

}

new FormInput().ReloadPage()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element_Id_1">1</div>
<div id="element_Id_2">2</div>
<div id="element_Id_3">3</div>
<div id="element_Id_4">4</div>
<div id="element_Id_5">5</div>
<div id="element_Id_6">6</div>
```

Comment: Great thanks for answer and detailed description of solution.

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with the rest of your project.